# Header Only Working Main Page

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to create new WordPress theme file but header only working on the main page. In other pages cannot working. 
so want to know what is the right way to call header.php into other files so it will work on other pages too.

Please take a look my header.php file

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="tr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Twin</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Twin">
    <meta name="author" content="Twin">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:300,400,700,800&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/jquery.fancybox.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/slick.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/site.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="main-header">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                            <img alt="" src="public/img/logo.svg" width="128" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                            <li><a href="/nedir">Nedir?</a></li>
                        </ul>


</body>
```

Comment: You should call get_header() in the page.php file or in your custom template file.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. You appear to have duplicate text in this question, you repeat the introduction and actual question. As for your actual question I don't know WordPress, but your HTML is badly formed, for example: near the bottom you have an opening `div` tag, then an un-ordered list, but no closing `div` tag. This might have something to do with why your header isn't appearing on all pages, but even if it isn't you should fix it up anyway.

Comment: You can see it. https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development. Hope this will help you

Comment: did you call your header.php file on the page.php?